# Trying to delete two cookies with the same name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

Framework/Language: ASP.NET MVC C#

Problem : trying to delete two HttpOnly cookies with the same name but different **domain**. One cookie is on .somedomain.com and the other one is on www.somedomain.com

Details:

The function to expire these cookies is listed below. It is expiring only one cookie, the last one - which seems to suggest that it is getting overwritten. Is that expected? Is there a workaround?

```
private static void ExpireCookie(string cookieName)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    context.Response.Cookies.Remove(cookieName);
    var cookieValue = string.Empty;
    if (context.Request.Browser["supportsEmptyStringInCookieValue"] == "false")
    var expirationTime = new DateTime(1999, 10, 12);
    var cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName, cookieValue)
    {
        HttpOnly = true,
        Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
        Expires = expirationTime,
        Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
        Domain = ".somedomain"
    };
    context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    //remove the cookieName on www.somedomain.com
     var cookie2 = new HttpCookie(cookieName, cookieValue)
    {
        HttpOnly = true,
        Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
        Expires = expirationTime,
        Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
    };
    context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To provide some closure, I ended up doing this:

- add the second with a different name, so `cookie2` above will be added as

  ```
  var cookie2 = new HttpCookie(cookieName +"2", cookieValue)
  {
  HttpOnly = true,
  Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
  Expires = expirationTime,
  Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
  };
  ```
- loop through all cookies and rename `cookieName`+`2` back to `cookieName`.

  ```
  for (var i = 0; i < currentResponse.Cookies.Count; i++)
      {
          var currentResponseCookie = currentResponse.Cookies[i];
          if (currentResponseCookie != null && currentResponseCookie.Name == cookieName + "2")
          {
              currentResponse.Cookies[i].Name = cookieName;
              break;
          }
      }
  ```

Fugly, but does the job for me.